# Codeigniter: passing a post variable from one function to another in a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am getting a variable called $msisdn from a view using post in one function (search_results). After doing the processing, I would like to use the same variable in another function(assign_role) currently,I am unable to do that since am getting this error

> Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: msisdn

. Below is my search_result function where am getting the post data:

```
public function search_results(){

    $msisdn =  $this->input->post('search_data');//getting data from the view


    if ($msisdn == false){

        $this->load->view('add_publisher');

    } else{
        $this->assign_role($msisdn); //passing the variable to another function

        $this->load->model('search_model');


        $data['result'] = $this->search_model->search_user($msisdn);
        $data1['box'] = $this->search_model->search_select($msisdn);

        $result = array_merge($data, $data1);  

        $this->load->view('add_publisher',$result);

        echo json_encode($result);
    }

}
```

I want to use $msisdn from above function in this function below:

```
public function assign_role($msisdn){

    //echo $msisdn['numm'];

    $publisher = $this->input->post('select');

    if ($publisher == false) {

        $this->load->view('add_publisher');

    } else {

        $data = array(
           'publisher' => true,
        );

        $this->load->model('insert_model');

        $data1 = $this->insert_model->search_group($msisdn, $data);             

            if ($data1 == true) {

                echo "Recorded updated succesfully";
                $this->load->view('add_publisher');

            } else {

                echo "Recorded not updated";
                $this->load->view('add_publisher');

            }

    }

}
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: "currently,I am unable to do that since it is breaking the whole app" This isn't enough information for us to assist you. Please edit your question to include the actual error message you are receiving.

Comment: @IanKemp I have edited the question.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: $data1 = $this->insert_model->search_group($msisdn, $data); on the assign_role function

Comment: removed greetings/salutations as per the SO ask questions rule

Comment: [I think you need to thoroughly review the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods).  In CodeIgniter, the methods are called via URL and its parameters come from the URI segments, not variables.  You should never call one method from another method.   [Create a custom library instead](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing variables from one function to another in the same controller can be achieved by using sessions. In Codeigniter, one can use flashdata like:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('info', $MyVariable);
```

Remember, flashdata is only available for the next server request then it will be automatically cleared.
Then it can be retrieved as:

```
$var = $this->session->flashdata('info');
```

If you want to keep the variable for one more server request, you can do this:

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('info');
```

Hope this will help someone faced with the problem.